# Changing financial contributions when renewing memberships

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, contributions

I have a site where users can select various contributions when they create their memberships.

Sometimes I renew members from the back-end of civi. However, when I click "add membership", I get a pop-up telling me that I can renew the membership instead of adding a new one.
That makes sense, so I click the link to go to the renewal screen.

The problem is that on the renewal screen in the back-end, I don't have the option to change a user's financial contributions.

Am I missing something? Or is this something that can be added in with a hook?

Thanks in advance,
-Joel

Comment: which version of CiviCRM are you using and did you manage to recreate the same against Demo site ?

Comment: Joels,  I am not sure what you're asking.  Are you trying to renew and add a  separate contribution?

Comment: Hi all, I'm running version 4.6.8 of civi and I tried on the demo site with the same results.

Comment: What I have is a membership with a price set. In the price set are the membership levels and various optional contributions that can be checked off. What happens with my users is that when they renew, we sometimes handle their renewals in the back-end. When you add a brand new membership and select the price set, you get the same checkboxes to select your desired contribution as in the front-end. However, sometimes our users want to change or select new contributions when they renew. When you renew in the back end, there are no options for this.

Comment: As an example, here is the add membership page with the contribution checkboxes: [link](http://joelwebservices.com/test/contrib-options.jpg)

And here is the renew membership page without the checkboxes: [link](http://joelwebservices.com/test/renew-options.jpg)

Comment: This seems like a necessary feature in civi. Can it be done? Any help would be appreciated.